# Is Car class violating Single Responsibility Principle?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, single-responsibility-principle

Even thought I think I understand Single Responsibility Principle and high/low cohesion principle, the following questions are still causing me some confusion

1) Assume `Planet` and `Bird` properties are put arbitrarily / at random in `Car` class ( ie. no code within `Car` needs or operates on the two objects returned by these two properties )  - in other words, `Planet` and `Bird` properties don't belong in Car class

a)

*SRP* states that object should have only one reason to change.

```
public class Car
{
    public void StartEngine()
    { ... }

    private Planet Planet
    {
        get { ... }
    }

    private Bird Bird
    {
        get { ... }
    }
}
```

Is `Car` class violating SRP? I would say it doesn't break SRP, since any changes to `Planet` or `Bird` instances don't propagate to the `Car` class?

b)

> Cohesion refers to how closely related methods and class level
>   variables are in a class.  In highly cohesive class all the methods
>   and class level variables are used together to accomplish a specific
>   task.  In a class with low cohesion functions are randomly inserted
>   into a class and used to accomplish a variety of different tasks

Assume that even though `Car` class contains these two random properties, it still accomplishes just a single specific task ( or several closely related task ):

Would we say that `Car` has  *low cohesion*, even though it still performs a specific task ( or several closely related tasks )?

2) Assume that `Planet` and `Bird` properties are used by methods of a `Car` instance  to accomplish a specific task, would then `Car` have *high cohesion*,  even though conceptually the two properties don't belong to `Car` ( and thus it would be better if instead `Planet` and `Bird` instances were passed as arguments to a methods of a `Car` which operate on them )

thank you

**HELTONBIKER:**

1)

> as you encapsulated Bird and Planet inside Car (worse yet if they are
>   private), so now Car class has THREE reasons to change:

I fail  to see how `Car`  has three reasons to change since in my first question `Car's` methods don't even operate on the two properties and thus any changes to `Planet's` and `Bird's` public API won't affect `Car` class?

2)

```
The problem here has two components:
1.  Bird and Planet are contained (as opposed to aggregated) in Car class;
2.  Bird and Planet are not conceptually related to Car, much less by some containment relationship.
```

a) This is confusing: aren't the chances ( at least with my first question ) of `Car` having to be modified due to modification of `Planet` or `Bird` instances exactly the same regardless of whether `Planet` and `Bird` instances are contained or aggregated?

b) In second question methods of `Car` do operate on the two properties in order to perform a **single specific task**, so aren't they conceptually at least somewhat related? Would you say that even in second question class has **low cohesion**, even though it performs only a **single task** ( and is using the two properties to accomplish the task )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The car class does have low cohesion, as it refers to classes wholly dissimilar to it's set of responsibilities. It also has a higher coupling surface, because since Planet and Bird are public, you've provided access to consumers to these properties, meaning that you're now adding two more "reasons for change" to any consumer, regardless of whether or not Car uses these internally.

At any rate, SRP has been violated if only because Car now has the responsibility of "a way to get planets or birds", disregarding any coupling/cohesion arguments.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that Planet and Bird are public, since I intended to make them private - I will edit the code and make them private

Comment: Making the two properties private did reduce the coupling, but I assume you'd argue Car class still has low cohesion?

Comment: Ok, with the modifications, I would say "Car does not *strictly* violate SRP, but it does exhibit low cohesion". Basically, you have the equivalent of unused private member variables now. Not a good practice, but not directly affecting SRP.

Comment: Does it exhibit low cohesion even in a second question, where the two properties are used by methods of a Car to accomplish a single specific task?

Comment: No, if the car requires a bird and a planet in order to accomplish a given responsibility, it absolutely needs access to those types. In that case, although it may appear "weird" given the example class names, it would not necessarily exhibit lowered cohesion.

Comment: "would not necessarily exhibit lowered cohesion" Even though the two properties conceptually don't belong to Car class and as such it would be better to pass them as parameters to Car methods?

Comment: @user437291 "better to pass them as parameters to Car methods?" you can take a look at the "aggregation over composition" principle, for example, here: http://ootips.org/uml-hasa.html

Comment: @user437291 eh, either way, it needs access to these types in order to execute it's responsibilities - if it has no need to maintain references to them, it'd be a poor design choice to hang on to them, but the cohesion has more to do with the interactions than pure composition. This is where the terms cohesion and coupling start to blur together a bit - in one way, they're describing two sides of the same "problem"

Comment: @heltonbiker: Why would aggregation be preferable over passing them as parameters?

Comment: Jer,  I must confess I'm somewhat confused now

Comment: @user437291 Ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Coupling_versus_Cohesion - by having Car interact with Planet and Bird, the **COUPLING** goes up, since it is talking to more things. The **COHESION** may or may not change at all, since from this do-nothing example, it's hard to say if the interaction of Car/Bird/Planet is RELATED. If the method in question was something like "Name car model from combination of planet and bird name", then (arguably) that is a cohesive, if very strange, method

Comment: 1 - "by having Car interact with Planet and Bird, the COUPLING goes up" Even if Car doesn't operate on two properties? 2 - "If the method in question was something like "Name car model from combination of planet and bird name", then (arguably) that is a cohesive," But didn't you in your previous comment remark that cohesion has more to do with interactions than pure composition? As such, that would imply that Class car in first question is cohesive, since its methods don't interact with two properties

Comment: @user437291 Re-read that referenced link:  "Coupling talks about the interdependencies between the various modules while cohesion describes how related functions within a module are." I may have poorly chosen my wording in my earlier comment, but (very) simply put, coupling is the # of things you need to talk to, cohesion is how "similar" all the things you do are.

Comment: It depends on what the association between the Car and Bird or Planet means. For example, the system might need to know what planet the car is on. Then Planet would make as much sense as a home address on a Person class. (And maybe the car transports a bird).

Answer (score 1):

1)
I would say that `Car` cannot hold `Planet` and `Bird`. That way Car has two different responsibilities: car functionality and holding some strange objects.
There should be some other object/class that would hold objects in world: eg: class `WorldContainer`

2)
I would say that both of your examples have low cohesion. Managing car and some different objects should be done using some other interface. Interface that would glue them together.

Comment: " ... Car has two different responsibilities" But within the context of SRP a Responsibility is defined as a 'Reason to change'. As such, couldn't we argue that Car still has only one reason to change?

Comment: but what if you change name of Bird class? then you would have to change the Car class. This is simple example of course, but somehow you can feel that something is wrong with such coupling. Another thing is that Car gives some public access to Bird and Planet members, which is a bit strange.

Comment: I agree if you change a public interface of a Bird class ( or even just name of Bird), then changes will ripple through to the Car class. But then any class referencing some other class could be considered highly coupled, even if it is using only a public interface of a referenced class

Comment: highy coupled class has meaningless connections, we need to minimize them. If a class has minimum connection then it is easy to react on a change.

Answer (score 1):

SRP means that a class should have only one reason to change.

So, a modification in Car class should mean that the Car conceptual model changed.

BUT, as you encapsulated Bird and Planet inside Car (worse yet if they are private), so now Car class has THREE reasons to change:

1. Modifying the Car conceptual model and/or behaviour;
2. Modifying the Bird conceptual model and/or behaviour;
3. Modifying the Planet conceptual model and/or behaviour;

The problem here has two components:

1. Bird and Planet are contained (as opposed to aggregated) in Car class;
2. Bird and Planet are not conceptually related to Car, much less by some containment relationship.

Or, plainly speaking (and I hope you did so as a didactic exercise), the architecture shown simply doesn't make sense.

---

Example with aggregation (in Python). The non-cohesive classes are defined outside the Car class definition, which references them. Car depends from Bird and Planet, but now Bird and Planet exist on their own.

```
class Bird():
    hasWings = True

class Planet():
    isFlat = False

class Car():
    owner = Bird()
    substrate = Planet()
```

---

Example with parameter-passing (just the car class, suppose the other classes are similar as above). Now the Car constructor (the `__init__` method in python) takes instances as parameters. This might or might not be prefered. The dependency and coupling remains, but perhaps more concrete now.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(bird, planet)
        owner = bird
        substrate = planet
```

---

In the end this whole issue of cohesion and coupling doesn't have so much to do with the software itself, but with the developers. Compilers won't mind if your namespaces, project folders and file distribution is messy, as long as it "compiles". But it wouldn't make ANY SENSE to do as you did (put a Bird and a Planet class inside a Car class). Just to begin, your versioning of each class would be very messed.

So, the purity you shouldn't violate is not that written in books for the sake of it. This purity is (or should have been) derived of human beings struggling with machine instructions. Object-Orientation, and Software Architecture in general, is not intended for the machine, but for the developer's (piece of) mind.

Comment: I'll try to edit my answer (I also need to clarify it for me, too :o)

Comment: I will really have to sleep on this and then get back :)